# Calculating derivative of linear distance

Tags: calculus

This is an exercise from Morris Kline's "Calculus: An Intuitive and Physical Approach".

> If an object moves along a circle of radius $R$, its position can be described by specifying the angle $\theta$ through which it has rotated. The derivative of $\theta$ with respect to $t$ (time) is called the angular velocity and is usually denoted by $\omega$; that is, $\theta ' = \omega$. The derivative of the angular velocity with respect to $t$ is called the angular acceleration and is usually denoted by $\alpha$; that is $\theta '' = \omega ' = \alpha$. The linear distance covered by the object is $s = R \theta$ if $\theta$ is measured in radians. Answer the following questions concerning circular motion:
>
> 1. What is the linear velocity? Answer from key: since $s = R \theta$, $s' = R \theta '$
> 2. What is the linear acceleration? Answer from key: from $s' = R \theta ' $, we have $s'' = R \theta '' = R \alpha$.

It is clear to me why $s'$ is the linear velocity, but I am unsure of how $s'$ was actually computed in the answer. The linear velocity should be the instantaneous rate of change in linear distance with respect to time, which is $\frac{ds}{dt}$. The variable $t$ does not appear in the equation for $s$, so how was $s'$ calculated? This is fairly early on in the book, so nothing like the chain rule has been covered.

Comment: Part of the issue is notation. I would have written $s(t) = R \theta(t)$, and so $s'(t) = R \theta'(t)$ and $s''(t) = R \theta''(t)$.

Comment: Probably not relevant here, but the discussion is a bit sloppy in my mind. $s$ is a distance, not a position, so while we can meaningfully talk about $s', s''$, it a little misleading to call $s',s''$ the linear velocity & acceleration respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the particle is moving the angle $\theta$ is changing with time so it is function of $t$. Thus
$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{d(R\theta)}{dt}=R\frac{d\theta}{dt}=R\omega.$$